# Nuance of accordingly and request for its equivalent phrase

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-requests, business-language

> I'll arrange the schedule **accordingly**.

The situation is I was asked to arrange a schedule to welcome a guest to our office from a US branch and I just got his preferred date and time to visit.
I was told my answer sounded a bit strange because "accordingly" is old-fashioned and too polite.

Is it true? If so, could you tell me any other suitable phrases for this situation?

Comment: Yes, it is old-fashioned and stilted. Just drop it altogether. The sentence is fine without it. My general advice is: the West is a lot more laid back, and less formal, than people give it credit for. Trying too hard for perfect formality, politeness, risks everything from pretentiousness to servility. Listen to your interlocutors and try to imitate then, match their register. But this is the best advice you'll be able to get here. Officially speaking, proof-reading (*is this sentence ok?*) and ghost-writing (*how can I say this better?*) are off-topic here. See the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: It sounds perfectly fine to me.  "Accordingly" implies that the arrangement of the schedule will take into account the concerns just discussed.  If you just say "I'll arrange the schedule" your listener has no such assurance.

Comment: @DanBron: I hope this question *doesn't* get flagged, as I think it's a legitimate one about **usage** rather than proofreading. In fact, I'm surprised to hear the phrase described as "strange" and "stilted". It's certainly a bit formal, but there are contexts where such formality is appropriate: for example, in an email reply to a CEO's instruction. In Australia it's not an unusual expression.

Comment: I have seen many phrases that are not very often spoken such as "per your request", "per requested", etc. used in e-mail correspondence. Accordingly might not be spoken very often, but I don't think it has any problem in formal e-mail correspondence. One thing I find very strange is your colleague in the U.S. I have worked with US colleagues for more than 20 years and I have never heard any one of them say my English is strange. Please check if (s)he is a native English speaker. That's plain rude.

Comment: @Chappo: It's about usage, but it is primarily opinion-based. And the judgment call about appropriate (!) usage for *appropriately* depends on the context - much more info about the context that we are given. And even then it is an individual judgment call - POB.

Comment: @Rathony I agree with you about the rudeness. When I see colleagues do that, my usual barb is "Yes, you're right, it does seem like English isn't perfectly natural for him. Let's switch to Hindi [or Spanish or German or whatever the native language of the victim is]". This works particularly well because I live in the US, and *nobody* is bilingual. Shuts them right up. Dicks. Anyway, I personally *despise* "per your request" and all other "email-ese". But I'm smart enough to keep mum on those peeves....

Comment: Consider that if you come into the guy's office and say the schedule needs to be rearranged to accommodate another speaker, he could reply "*I'll* arrange the schedule" (meaning "Butt out -- I'm in control here"), or he could reply "I'll arrange the schedule accordingly" (meaning "I'll include that change in the final schedule").

Comment: Understand that "accordingly" is not just a bit of polite happy talk.  It means "in accordance with the stated objectives".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are trying to make a point of being informal, there is no reason (other than it would be a shorter sentence) to drop the word. If anything you will end up sounding more professional and possibly more intelligent. Basically: it's a perfectly everyday word, use it if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience in the legal profession, the adverb "accordingly" is most often used in its written form by attorneys at the end of "cease and desist" demand letters threatening litigation as:  "GOVERN YOURSELVES ACCORDINGLY" (traditionally written in all capital letters), which is obviously not intended to be polite or kind (it's a demand after all).  Therefore, when I see the written word used elsewhere, the usage never strikes me as polite or kind, as I'm predisposed to viewing it from the perspective of its usage in a legal context.  Additionally, I rarely hear the word "accordingly" spoken by others (but more frequently hear less negatively-charged synonyms such as:  so, therefore, thus, subsequently, correspondingly, respectively).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly does make the sentence more polite and friendly but it is an old fashioned word and I feel a little out of context here.

It would have made more sense if you were given something and you had to work with respect to that (**according** to that)

If you want to have the politeness and not sound strange, how about these alternatives:

> I'll arrange the schedule surely.

or better still,

> Sure, I'll prepare the itinerary

Comment: I may be old-fashioned, but IMHO there is *nothing* old-fashioned about *appropriately* - not in AmE usage anyway (IMO). I'm guessing, because you and @DanBron both feel that it is old-fashioned, that this might depend on culture & context.

Comment: FWIW (maybe not much), this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accordingly%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+accordingly%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccordingly%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccordingly%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) suggests that its usage has declined only slightly in the last 50 years.

Comment: "Surely" does not have anywhere near the same meaning as "accordingly".

Comment: @HotLicks, I did not suggest `surely` has the same meaning as `accordingly`

Comment: But you propose replacing a meaningful word with a relatively meaningless one.  "Accordingly" has a meaning -- it means "in accordance with the stated objectives".

Comment: So you agree that I did not suggest they mean the same, just proposed an alternative as it fits the situation better here. Surely, `surely` is not meaningless?

Comment: Using "surely" does not express the intent of the original sentence.

Comment: Darshan, I don't think this answer is useful. Your first sentence is quite bizarre - not merely in the location of **surely** within the sentence, but in its usage as a replacement for "accordingly". I've never heard it used in that way. Also, you provide no evidence to support your assertion that the word is "old fashioned".